# image size is not changing

Tags: php, html, image, height

I have the following code for displaying an image. It works but it doesn't change the size of the image if I change the height and width values in here.

```
<img src="<?php echo trim($user_data['profilepicture'])?>" height='10' width='10'>
```

Can somebody help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

It's `width` and `height`, not weight.

Comment: <img src="<?php echo trim($user_data['profilepicture']); ?>" height="10" width="10" alt="" />